# LPAD or RPAD Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule

How to use `LPAD` or `RPAD`, I tried some examples from

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.5

```
LPAD( Account.Name , 2 )
```

Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).

```
LPAD('my_company.com', 14, 'z')
```

Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (true or false).

```
LPAD( Account.Name , 5 [, 'a'])
```

Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: What is return type of your formula field

Comment: Return type is text or string, I am New to salesforce and Just want to know how these validation Rule works,  just need an example to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula field with return type as `Text`. LPAD and RPAD returns a text value not boolean. See the image below. 
From doc:-

> LPAD inserts characters you specify to the left-side of a text string.
>   RPAD inserts characters that you specify to the right-side of a text.

string.
[image]
It will return output like this. Try with different values.
[image]